# Rails 4.2 Engine assets are not found by Application mounting the Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

My engine layout files cannot find their own assets.  Troubleshooting this error:

```
The asset "compost/application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

I have an Engine which I call Compost.  For debugging it is installed under myapp/vendor.  This Engine defines the layout, CSS and JS.  In the Compost `application.html.erb` I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "compost/application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "compost/application" %>
```

The following files exist on disk:

- /var/www/myapp/vendor/compost/app/assets/javascripts/compost/application.js
- /var/www/myapp/vendor/compost/app/assets/stylesheets/compost/application.css

I have tried every combination of forcing the paths (many examples here on Stack Overflow) and defining the include tags that I can think of. I have tried altering `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` even though the docs say I should not have to. None of the combinations I'm trying work.

Assets do precompile successfully.

See also: the [Rails Engine docs on Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#assets).

In myapp (not the Engine) `config/initializers/assets.rb` I have:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback = false
```

This way I am sure to see missing assets.

In myapp's controller, at the time it is about to render the index page, `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` has these values:

```
[0] = "/var/www/myapp/app/assets/images"
[1] = "/var/www/myapp/app/assets/javascripts"
[2] = "/var/www/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets"
[3] = "/var/www/myapp/vendor/assets/javascripts"
[4] = "/var/www/myapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets"
[5] = "/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts"
[6] = "/var/www/myapp/vendor/compost/app/assets/images"
[7] = "/var/www/myapp/vendor/compost/app/assets/javascripts"
[8] = "/var/www/myapp/vendor/compost/app/assets/stylesheets"
[9] = "/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts"
```

From the Rails console:

```
[5] pry(main)> Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets
=> {"crappy-logo-192.png"=>"crappy-logo-192-d8e1a64a50bfa2d8f1d0e21c4388965a40bc4dad334d85b61529319492f8565c.png",
 "application.js"=>"application-001f5e28177bd346911da447aac242092556172f3b8a70252fe73908c56fc29d.js",
 "application.css"=>"application-332b5766465b8e232789ef47345e8d8a9b8c4a3163244264ba02f39d7dd1f9cb.css",
 "compost/application.js"=>"compost/application-f9d8e5ce8f528d997d58156ff5f8c1d4b0741ac22b367a6a6294b3c7e9758e96.js",
 "compost/application.css"=>"compost/application-092c8366f9406ff8b64d93866be4d7efb151aba3c3cddbc325c0d386575242bb.css"}
[6] pry(main)> Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets['compost/application.css'].present?
=> true
```

All signs and docs indicate this "should just work."  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had `config.asset.compile = false` and apparently this:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bin/bundle exec rake assets:precompile -vvv
```

Is not doing what I think it is: precompiling assets.

Comment: The option is called `config.assets.compile` (assets in the plural), for those copying-pasting.